# How to check for primary key and foreign key condition in EF core right?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a Post entity with Id and User properties.
User is IdentityUser.
I don't have a UserId property on my entity as I don't need it.

How can I check that post belongs to current user in optimal way?
I thought about this

```
var currentUser = await userManager.GetUserAsync(httpAccessor.HttpContext.User);
if (!await context.Posts.FromSql(
    @"SELECT TOP 1 UserId
      FROM Posts
      WHERE Id = {0}", postId).Any(Id => Id == currentUser.Id))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Post does not belong to current user.");
```

or this

```
if (!await context.Posts.AnyAsync(p => p.Id == post.Id && p.User.Id == currentUser.Id))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Post does not belong to current user.");
```

But it does not work.

This is an SQL generated from the second option

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Posts] AS [p]
        INNER JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [p.User] ON [p].[UserId] = [p.User].[Id]
        WHERE ([p].[Id] = @__post_Id_0) AND ([p.User].[Id] = @__currentUser_Id_1))
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END
```

Comment: Can you show us your Post and User Models code?

Answer (score 0):

For your case "optimal" way is to read Post object from DB (`var post = await context.Posts.SingleAsync(x => x.Id = postId);` and check `User` on it.

This will cause reading all properties from `Post`, including large texts (post body, etc). You may try to avoid this by selecting only specific properties to anonymous class:

```
var postUser = await context.Posts
    .Where(x => x.Id = postId)
    .Select(x => new {
         x.Id,
         UserId = x.User.Id
    })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Well I thought about that and it must produce the SQL I desired but it is more verbose in LINQ syntax.